# Do you receive achievements if you complete them without using the save game feature?

Tags: starcraft-2

Do you only receive achievements for campaign missions if you complete them without using the save game feature.  I completed a couple last night but had to restart from a last save point when I died.  I completed the missions along with all the optional objectives but never got the achievements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. I also had the save game issue after the patch but I loaded a game in the hyperion and it was good. used a lot of saves, I actually fell about a couple attacks short of getting the hard achievement for "A Sinister Turn" so i loaded an autosave and finished the mission from there(and got the achievement also)

Answer (score 4):

It has to do with with the a Starcraft2 patch

From the Starcraft2 [forums](http://starcraft2forum.org/forums/showthread.php?p=379588):

> Anyone who had a saved game before
>   today[sic before patch] will not get
>   achievements for that mission.
>   Brilliantly to play a saved game which
>   is old (patch wise) SC2 throws you off
>   of Battle.net to play the mission
>   without the new updates... and since
>   you're not on Battle.net you won't get
>   the achievements.

Comment: This was a save file created after the patch 1.1 dropped.  It was one of the mission auto saves I used all within one play session.

Answer (score 0):

That may be a bug with the latest patch.  I've heard many reports of various problems with campaign saves.

Prior to the patch (haven't played campaign since) I have always received achievements with liberal usage of saves.  The [patch notes](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/842870) have no indication that that would have changed.

Also, maybe obvious but make sure you're not playing offline mode (unlikely as if I remember correctly the mode is only available when you don't have an internet connection)