# Do I have to complete a mission to earn an achievement in SC2

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you receive achievements if you complete them without using the save game feature?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/do-you-receive-achievements-if-you-complete-them-without-using-the-save-game-fea)

I have just started a level, quickly got an achievement I needed. Now can I just quit the level and still have the achievement or do I have to play and complete the level before I gain the achievement?

Comment: Related: [Do you receive achievements if you complete them without using the save game feature?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/do-you-receive-achievements-if-you-complete-them-without-using-the-save-game-fea)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't have to complete the mission, however you do have to be connected online.

Answer (score 2):

No, you just need to meet all requirements for a certain achievement to obtain it.

Plus:

- You must be online
- You must not have cheated during the mission or any other mission before on this particular scenario / save game.